# WPF won't print most of the time

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm a beginner in WPF and I have this problem with printing. I use the following code :

```
    public static void PrintImageFile(string ImagePath, int ImageCopyCount, PageOrientation ImagePageOrientation = PageOrientation.Unknown, PrintQueue Printer = null, string PrintingName = "")
    {            
        PrintDialog printDialog = SetPrintDialog(ImageCopyCount, ImagePageOrientation, Printer);
        BitmapImage imageToPrint = BitmapImageFromPath(ImagePath);
        PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
        Size size = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisualToPrint = BitmapImageToDrawingVisual(imageToPrint, size);

        try
        {
            printDialog.PrintVisual(drawingVisualToPrint, PrintingName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Info("Error in PrintImageFile : " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it won't print most of the times. In those cases the print job is briefly displayed in the printer's list of print jobs and then disappears. There's no error message of any kind and the program behaves as if PrintVisual had never been executed.
Around 1 out of 6-7 times though, the printing occurs exactly as expected ...

The printer works fine otherwise.

I have spent a lot of time trying to understand this and I haven't seen anyone having the same issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is content in drawingVisualToPrint?  This is a reach but the print queue may be determining there is nothing in the print job so it drops is/

Comment: drawingVisualToPrint has content, that was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of this behavior.

It is caused by the manifest the program uses in order to automatically execute as administrator.
Can’t remember where I got it from but here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>

    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

I’m sure this is what’s causing it, I have made different test projects. As soon as i remove the manifest in the project properties (under Application), printing occurs as expected.

Still need to execute program as administrator though.

Anyone who has any experience with this kind of issue?

(I’m running debugger under windows 7)